# cakePHP Paginate and sort by DESC

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.5

At the moment i query my db with this query below and it works great , it joins with another table.

```
 $tapplicant = $this->Tapplicant->find(
    'all',
    array(
        'fields' => array(
            'Tapplicant.*',
            'Toutcome.*'

        ),
         'order' => array('Tapplicant.AppDate' => 'DESC'),
        'joins' => array(
            array(
                'table' => 'toutcome',
                'alias' => 'Toutcome',
                'type' => 'INNER',
                'conditions' => array('Tapplicant.AppID = Toutcome.AppID' )


            )
        ),
        'limit' => 15
    )
);
```

I have setup a Pagenator :

```
 public $paginate = array (
'order' => array('Tapplicant.AppID' => 'desc'),
'limit' => 15,

);
```

What i need to know is how do i :

- Add Paginator
- Using on the current date CURDATE()

I jsut dont know where to add it in.

Comment: What are you wanting to do with CURDATE()?

Comment: The results must only be for today's date @drmonkeyninja

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller:-

```
$this->paginate = array(
    'fields' => array(
        'Tapplicant.*',
        'Toutcome.*'
    ),
    'joins' => array(
        array(
            'table' => 'toutcome',
            'alias' => 'Toutcome',
            'type' => 'INNER',
            'conditions' => array('Tapplicant.AppID = Toutcome.AppID' )


        )
    ),
    'conditions' => array(
        'Tapplicant.AppDate' => date('Y-m-d')
    ),
    'order' => array('Tapplicant.AppDate' => 'DESC'),
    'limit' => 15
);

$this->set('tapplicant', $this->paginate());
```

Comment: I still need to add : $this->set('tapplicant', $tapplicant ); as i am displaying the results on the index page using <?php foreach ($tapplicant as $tapplicant) : ?> @drmonkeyninja

Comment: @MaxPayneUK sorry forgot to include that step. I've updated the answer accordingly. :-)

Comment: I just had to adjust ('Tapplicant.AppDate' => date('Y-m-d') ) WITH  'Tapplicant.AppDate >=' => date('y-m-d')  and it worked great, thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You can do this right in the find:

```
$tapplicant = $this->Tapplicant->find(
    'all',
    array(
        'fields' => array(
            'Tapplicant.*',
            'Toutcome.*'

        ),
        'joins' => array(
            array(
                'table' => 'toutcome',
                'alias' => 'Toutcome',
                'type' => 'INNER',
                'conditions' => array('Tapplicant.AppID = Toutcome.AppID' )


            )
        ),
        'limit' => 15,
        'order' => array('Tapplicant.AppID' => 'desc'),
    )
);
```

And leave paginate like this:

```
public $paginate = array('limit' => 15);
```

If you only want the posts from the current day, just add this to the find:

```
'conditions' => array('Tapplicant.created' => date('Y-m-d')),
```